# Reusing Memory Streams Attached images

Tags: c#, memorystream

`I was trying to send Chart from my windows from directly  to mail body`
`Here i bind "runtimeImage.png" with MemoryStream`

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment _ms1 = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Attachments(Data[i][4].ToString()), "runtimeImage.png");
mail.Attachments.Add(_ms1);
mail.Body += "<img src='runtimeImage.png' />";
```

`Here i convert Chart to image and create MemoryStream`

```
private MemoryStream Attachments(string type)
        {
            getChartData(type);
            byte[] bytes = null;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                chart.SaveImage(memoryStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
                bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            return new MemoryStream(bytes);
        }
```

But when ever i send mail only first picture going in mail body, image not changing,
How can i clear and reuse MemoryStream.

Note :I am new to developing (fresh Graduate) and doing this by curiosity.

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with reusing memory streams?

Comment: Note that I've removed your `[winforms]` tag because this question doesn't relate to Windows Forms.

Comment: Sir , let me tell you first that , i am trying to create and generate dynamic chart and everytime my system found data in table , i will send appropriate personal thats why I tried this why ,  And i dont have any guidline how to do it more optimized way.

Comment: So...what does this have to do with reusing memory streams? Every time you call `Attachments` you get a brand new `MemoryStream`.

Comment: but my image is not changing,and some one told me because of my memory saved the picture thats why i am getting same image everytime.

Comment: Are you perhaps reusing the same mail objects for each email you send?

Comment: Yes. Same Chart but value different.

Comment: I suggest not reusing the mail objects then.

Comment: ok, i will try it now.